# UNPIVOT not getting NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following :

```
SELECT Custid, Shipperid, Freight
FROM Sales.FreightTotals
UNPIVOT( Freight FOR Shipperid IN([1],[2],[3]) ) AS U;
```

I have the following result :

```
custid shipperid freight
1      1         25
1      3         100
2      2         75
```

My expected output after getting NULL values :

```
custid shipperid freight
1      1         25
1      2         NULL
1      3         100
2      1         NULL
2      2         75
2      3         NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE to get NULL as 0.00 for example then replace the 0.00 by NULL using NULLIF() :

```
WITH C AS
(
SELECT custid,
ISNULL([1], 0.00) AS [1],
ISNULL([2], 0.00) AS [2],
ISNULL([3], 0.00) AS [3]
FROM Sales.FreightTotals
)
SELECT custid, shipperid, NULLIF(freight, 0.00) AS freight
FROM C
UNPIVOT( freight FOR shipperid IN([1],[2],[3]) ) AS U;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is considered a *feature* of `unpivot`.  Use `apply` instead:

```
SELECT ft.custid, v.shipperid, v.freight
FROM Sales.FreightTotals ft CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (1, ft.[1]), (2, ft.[2]), (3, ft.[3])) AS v(shipperid, freight);
```

Comment: If I use OUTER APPLY I get the same result. What's the difference then?

Comment: @mohamed-mhiri . . . In this case there is no difference.  I'm surprised you didn't accept this answer -- it is simpler and does not confuse `NULL` with `0`.